# Cucumber tests' step definition should be able to handle "a" and "an" [regex related]

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber

I have these two tests. They pretty much do the same thing, so I don't want to write two separate steps that do pretty much the same thing.

```
Scenario: I delete a question link
  Given   I am on the home page
    When  I "delete" a "question" link
    Then  A "question" link should be "deleted"

Scenario: I delete a account link
  Given   I am on the home page
    When  I "delete" an "account" link
    Then  An "account" link should be "deleted"
```

If I wanted to write a step that works with `I "delete" a "question" link` and `I "delete" an "account" link`, how would I modify the following regex to handle "a" and "an".

```
/^I "([^"]*)" a/an?? "([^"]*)" link$/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
/^I "([^"]*)" an? "([^"]*)" link$/
```

The question mark denotes that the "n" character can be part of the string but doesn't have to

If there's any "value" in the type you could also use:

```
/^I "([^"]*)" (a|an) "([^"]*)" link$/
```

Comment: Funny, because he/she almost had it by accident, with the ``??``.

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap your original regex in a group? `(an?)`